# Technically, is the closed [1] interval legitimate?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, real-numbers

In mathematics, a (real) [interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)) is a set of real numbers with the property that any number that lies between two numbers in the set is also included in the set. For example, the set of all numbers x satisfying 0 ≤ x ≤ 1 is an interval which contains 0 and 1, as well as all numbers between them.

it seems that the definition does not force left-bounded **must be** smaller than right-bounded.

so, is the closed interval [1] legitimate technically?

generally [n], where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the natural number set.

Comment: did you mean to ask if the *empty* interval is legitimate?  $[0,1]$ is a closed interval

Comment: @J.W.Tanner generally \[n], where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the natural number set.

Comment: according to that page you linked, {$n$} is a *degenerate* interval if $n\in\Bbb R$

Comment: If you want to discuss comparing "left-bounded" to "right-bounded", it helps to use some notation for these.  The definition of interval that you first introduced does not mention or rely on those ideas.

Comment: Would your please make some examples about the notation?

Comment: The set consisting of just the number $1$ is a closed interval, but if you want to display it as a closed interval, you have to write it as $[1,1]$. $[1]$ is not a correct use of interval notation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks man! Please mv your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Your wish is my command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set consisting of just the number $1$ is a closed interval, but if you want to display it as a closed interval, you have to write it as $[1,1]$. Writing $[1]$ is not a correct use of interval notation.